# Parse.com JavaScript containsAll does not work

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an **article** object which include an array field **tags**. I want to find all articles contains certain tags. Here is my code:

```
  var Article = Parse.Object.extend('Article');
  var query = new Parse.Query(Article);
  query.containsAll('tags',tags);
  query.find({
    success : function(results) {
      console.log(results);
```

The **tags** in my code is an array like, ["tag1","tag2"]. My code always return empty. Anything wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using containedIn function? If you pass an array to it, it searches for the requested value.

```
query.containedIn("tags", tags);
```